# Output Multi-dimensional array values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional associative array and display its values. Originally in the code below I had string names instead of numbers. However this gave me an "undefined constant" error. When I replaced the strings with numbers, all it prints out is "arrayarrayarray". Can anyone tell me

(a) how to put strings in instead of numbers

(b) How to get the values inside of the array instead of it just printing out "array".

When I code     "echo $myArray[1];" it outputs "array" instead of the values inside of that array.

```
  $myArray = array( 
            0 => array
        (
        "physics" => 35,        
        "maths" => 30,      
        "chemistry" => 39       
        ),
        1 => array
                (
                "physics" => 30,
                "maths" => 32,
                "chemistry" => 29
                ),
                2 => array
                (
                "physics" => 31,
                "maths" => 22,
                "chemistry" => 39
                )
         );

     echo  count ($myArray);
    ?>
    <p>

    <?php

       echo $myArray[1];

     ?>

     <p>
     <?php

      // On the line below, loop through the array and output
      // *all* of the values to the page:



    for ($i= 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++)

    echo $myArray[$i];


      ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "how to put strings in instead of numbers"?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it wouldn't hurt for you to read a bit on [Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

Sure when you write `echo $myArray[1];` it prints out `array` for you, because that's what you have - a nested array.

To use associative arrays - "*put strings instead of numbers*" as you say, following example can be used:

```
$myArray = array( 
    "Johnson" => array (
       "physics" => 35,        
       "maths" => 30,      
       "chemistry" => 39       
    ),
    "Smith" => array (
       "physics" => 35,        
       "maths" => 30,      
       "chemistry" => 39       
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $myArray[1]['physics'];
```

will display

```
35
```

and:

```
foreach( $myArray as $childArray )
{
    echo $childArray['physics'];
}
```

will print:

```
35
30
31
```

But as @Trogvar already told you: [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).